Surface lines correlated to infilled area below surface
I'm wrestling with a surface layer variation that is occurring when there is an infilled / deeper shape directly below the surface. The lines line up perfectly with the boundaries of the shape that's behind the surface.
I'm using BambuStudio with a P1S. The preset settings all produce this same result.
I'd love to know what setting I should be playing with in order to avoid this. There's certainly nothing weird with the models I'm importing.
Back image and front image attached.



Usually, this defect is seen in the lower end printers, it is most probably a positioning error. However, I wouldn't say this printer is on the lower end of the market. What print speed did you use?

Did you use the P1S or the P1P? The text is different from the tag.
